# How to batch Check geometry in ArcGIS for a list of datasets from a CSV?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

We have around 50+ gdb's(in different folders) which has 450 datasets in total. Among the 450, we have a list of 100 feature dataset's for which we have to do QAQC. So is it possible to batch **Check geometry** process ? From ArcGIS's help page I've come across this http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/check-geometry.htm This code works great for a single gdb to check geometry of all the datasets within that gdb. I would like to run Check geometry process only for particular datasets within particular gdb's.

Eg: D:\QAQC\f_c.csv This will have the list of datasets for which Check geometry process has to be run. CSV will have file path like

E:\Chk\A\ddd.gdb\Feature_dataset_1

E:\Chk\B\eee.gdb\Feature_dat_1

I know the file_path should not be represented like this. Just to throw some idea on what I want, I've mentioned the path like this

Edit:

This code worked like a charm

```
import csv
import arcpy

csvpath = r"path\to\csv"
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
arcpy.CheckGeometry_management(fcs, "outtable")
```

Comment: I think this question is pretty straight-forward at this point and should be reopened.  It's really just about iterating a CSV, which is a very simple thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a way to read the CSV file with python, and for that you can use the `csv` module. So, very simply:

```
import csv
import arcpy

csv_path = r"path\to\csv"
with open(csv_path, "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:

        # you can access columns in the row by using indices
        # because the row is a list of its values

        fcpath = row[0] # or whatever column
        arcpy.CheckGeometry_management(fcpath, "outtable")
```

You could optionally make a list of all the feature class paths and pass that to a single Check Geometry function (instead of running the function once per feature class).  I assume that the only main difference would be in the output table.  You could use less lines to achieve this:

```
import csv
import arcpy

csv_path = r"path\to\csv"
with open(csv_path, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]

arcpy.CheckGeometry_management(fcs, "outtable")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked great. Only thing is "csvpath" has to be changed csv_path while defining the path

Comment: oops, good catch, sorry for the sloppiness. I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the following logic to iterate a csv and find related feature dataset (fd) within folders of gdbs:

1. Use [arcpy.da.search cursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to iterate over .csv and get field fd path value
2. Create another function or nest os.walk method within step 1 and find all gdb within parent directory of directories
3. Create another function or nest (Once .gdb found) [arcpy.da.walk](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) to iterate over gdb to look for found fd name in step 2
4. Continue on with check geometry logic...

Comment: i want only particular datasets to be checked. The name of the dataset's to be checked will be in a csv file with the path details (eg: D:\RD\aaa.gdb\Dataset_1)

Comment: Your question needs re-worded, it seemed like you only needed help accessing many gdb within many directories, "This code wokrs great for a single gdb. I've no clue how to do it for n number of gdb's at a time."

Comment: I've edited the question.