# How to make an arcpy tool to take multiple inputs csv/text lists, instead of a single input?

Tags: arcpy

It's been only few days that i've been working in python environment.

Based on [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190668/how-to-batch-check-geometry-in-arcgis-for-a-list-of-datasets-from-a-csv), i've been trying to batch few process for our QAQC task's. At certain times, like when i use Describe.(path_in_a_csv) i am always getting this error "Input value is not valid type". Even [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191202/problem-in-reading-mosaic-dataset-path-from-a-csv-file), only with the help of Philip i was able to make the code run successfully. I tried the same thing arcpy.ExportMosaicDatasetPaths_management(path_in_a_csv,"Output"). The error was "not able to execute the tool".

Though i've been trying to understand this for the past couple of days, i couldn't able to crack it. It'll be of great help if anyone shed a bit of light on how to go from here.

```
import csv
import arcpy
from os import path
csvpath = r"D:\QAQC\Chk_Rep_File_list.csv"
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
   fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
for fc in fcs:
   desc = arcpy.Describe(fcs)

RuntimeError: Object: Describe input value is not valid type
```

Comment: This line `desc = arcpy.Describe(fcs)` should be `desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `desc = arcpy.Describe(fcs)` should be `desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)` - you have `fcs` which is a list of all files from your CSV, and instead it should be `fc` for each file one at a time (since you're looping through fcs one at a time in the `for fc in fcs:` loop).

```
import csv
import arcpy
from os import path
csvpath = r"D:\QAQC\Chk_Rep_File_list.csv"
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
for fc in fcs:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

    print "Name = {}".format(desc.name)
    print "\tData Type = {}".format(desc.dataType)
    print "\tPath = {}".format(desc.path)
```

As you had it, you would get no feedback if the script ran successfully.  I have added the three `print` statements at the end to output some results from your `Describe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Worked perfectly. But if i apply the same thing to this code, it didn't work. This is the thing thats been bugging me for days. Why it's not working for this code ? arcpy.ExportMosaicDatasetPaths_management(fcs) - part

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191202/problem-in-reading-mosaic-dataset-path-from-a-csv-file

Comment: at a guess you'd need to use `fc` not `fcs`, but also include an output table as per [Export Mosaic Dataset Paths](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/export-mosaic-dataset-paths.htm)

Comment: but best put in a new question I think

Comment: For the sake of explaining it to you, i've omitted that "Output_table" part. Anyway will try to figure it out